# Getting properties from subclass SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working with `Sprite-Kit`. I have created a subclass `SKObjectNode` of `SKSpriteNode` because I wanted to add a property called `objectType`.

Now that I have that property, I do:

```
SKObjectNode *myObject = [SKObjectNode spriteNodeWithColor.......];
myObject.objectType = ......;
```

I have successfully added a new property to the object (success).

---

Now the problem, I want to get that property inside the `didBeginContact` method.
First I try:

```
SKObjectNode *nodeA = contact.bodyA.node; // incompatible pointer types init .. with an expression type of SKNode *
NSLog("%@", nodeA.objectType) // no error
```

I ran the app to test.

When the `NSLog` gets called, a `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error is thrown, and terminates the app.

How do I get the objectType on the `SKObjectNode`?
Or is there a better way of doing this? I just want to add that property to my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears because `contact.bodyA.node` is a type of SKNode not SKObjectNode you have to tell the compiler that it's going to be SKObjectNode to do that you can use cast:

```
SKObjectNode *nodeA = (SKObjectNode*)contact.bodyA.node;
```

Now the compiler know that the object is type of SKObjectNode.